# How can I test the NGINX 5xx error configuration (generate a 5xx error)?

Tags: nginx

I am setting up a new web server using NGINX and I would like to test the error page configuration. This is easy enough to do for a 404 but I want to test the 5xx configuration and so need to at least be able to generate one of the 500-series errors from a request.

Can anyone give me a clue please as to how to do that?

Comment: Use `return 500;` or any other code, it will trigger your custom error page :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you could use `try_files` with a nonexistent file. The command has a fallback option that can throw an error code of your choice: `try_files file ... =code;` [guide here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#trying-several-options), [docs here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

```
server {  
    listen 80;
    root /www/data;

    location /throw_500 {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =503;
    }
}
```

In this case, just access `http://server/throw_500` (empty `$uri` passed) and the error will be thrown.

Comment: Many that @rgon, what you've given does work and I've given it an upvote. However, there is also a simpler answer based on Ivan's comment.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use a non-existant location containing a `return 500;` statement.

```
server {  
    listen 80;

    location /throw503 {
        return 503;
    }
}
```

Many thanks to Ivan and rgon. I couldn't see the wood for the trees